# AngularJS form validation with RegEx not working

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am trying to validate phone number with RegEx. Below is my requirement. 10 Digits alpha/numeric, where an Alpha CHAR is in the 4th position (not including hyphen). For example: 586R410056

```
NNN ANN NNNN
(NNN) ANN NNNN
NNN-ANN-NNNN
(NNN) ANN-NNNN
1NNN ANN NNNN
1(NNN) ANN NNNN
1NNN-ANN-NNNN
1(NNN) ANN-NNNN
NNN.ANN.NNNN
(NNN-ANN-NNNN)
```

I came up with following RegEx, but it's not working in AngularJS form. RegEx:

```
^[1]?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{2}[-.\s]?\d{4}\)?$
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jWfYGq7hP2dxuFgWSfq?p=preview)

Comment: Well in the plunker angular isn't even initialized, you may want to start there.

Comment: Two resources for you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages, and their example http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. You should also read up on setting up forms in Angular (specifically, you need to include novalidate on the form)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:: **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgGqvR0HfAjgzoSetkZ5?p=preview)**

```
  <form class="form-inline container-fluid" name="userForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="addBTNWTNModalCotroller.selectedItem.lecBtn" ng-pattern="/^1?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?[a-zA-Z]\d{2}[-.\s]?\d{4}\)?$/" ng-change="addBTNWTNModalCotroller.onBtnFieldChange()" name="btn" required style="width: 90%;"
      placeholder="Enter here..."> 
      <div ng-show="userForm.btn.$touched">
        <span class="error-text" ng-show="userForm.btn.$error.required">
                  <span class="icon-ICON_WARNING"></span> BTN is required.
        </span>
        <span class="error-text" ng-show="userForm.btn.$error.pattern">
                   <span class="icon-ICON_WARNING"></span> Please enter valid BTN.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```